# Can I return to Australia after serving an entry ban due to a prior overstay?

Tags: visas, australia, uk-citizens, overstaying, visa-bans

I am English and I left Australia in 2015 upon which I received a ban for 3 years for overstaying my welcome, even through I was granted a visa (or what I thought was sponsorship visa for 5 years).

It is now 2020 I have served my ban and learned from my past mistakes of being gullible and not researching into the visa company enough. I wish to make a return now that I am 30 and working as a youth worker with children abused and who have left home, but I am not sure about the visa options and if my past ban may become an issue. I was never in trouble in Australia I worked my whole time I was there and left to go on holiday and wasn't granted re-entry. Any advice please on where to begin as I unsure of what my next step is, Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to visit or work there? Getting a visit visa with a lengthy overstay on your record seems unlikely, even if the actual ban has expired.

Comment: I would like the option to work there and visit again. There has been people that have re-visited the country after a ban. All I want to do is at least try

Comment: Surely you were in trouble in Australia the moment you overstayed your visa? They just didn't catch you.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you research the availability of Australian visas for the purpose of work. You can do that on [this Australian government webpage](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-finder/work), which is apt to be more dependable than any of the multitude of private visa agencies which do nothing more than submit your information to the Australian government, and charge you for doing so...and thus encourage you to apply for a visa so they can stay in business.

Because you previously overstayed, and thereafter were refused entry to Australia and banned, it very likely that your visa application will be denied. Australia's view — evidenced by the ban — is that you did not follow the rules. They'll think you'll do the same if again admitted.

It is not impossible to get a visa, but you must convince them that this time you'll follow the rules. Just saying so won't be enough; you'll have to demonstrate a settled and dependable life. See [this thread](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153986/i-was-deported-and-my-ban-period-ends-this-year-will-i-be-able-to-return-to-the/154007#comment383585_154007) for a similar discussion vis-a-vis the US.

All in all, your plan to return to Australia in the near future for work does not have a significant chance of success.

Answer (score -1):

No no no no no .

Yes of course can apply for new visas. I am in your exact position ban lifted in 2020. So you can apply for any visa. That suits u and were u meet requirements. Just apply but do not withhold any information an previous ban when and why it happened in detail and how you see how silly us been and demonstrate that everything that's your new Visa requires of you have bulletproof. Explain that u are now fully aware of every last DETAIl of visa requirement now. If they dont let people in after a 3 year ban it would be a lifetime ban. So go for goodluck.

Comment: Please use full words in English. So not u but you and such.

Comment: I tried to edit but the answer did not make enough sense, likely I missed out some more language liberties.